# RXSwift How to create wrapper for delegate method with return value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a  wrapper for delegate in RXSwift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,movedRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,toIndexRowPath destinationRowIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

And they looks like

```
public var rx_itemRowMoved: ControlEvent<ItemMovedEvent> {
    let source: Observable<ItemMovedEvent> = rx_delegate.observe("tableView:movedRowAtIndexPath:toIndexRowPath:")
        .map { a in
            return ((a[1] as! NSIndexPath), (a[2] as! NSIndexPath))
    }

    return ControlEvent(events: source)
}
```

But I have delegate with return value

```
 func selectionViewForTableView(tableView: UITableView,destinitionCell cell:UITableViewCell,toIndexRowPath destinationRowIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIView
```

how I can implement  wrapper for this delegate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this. You can implement this method in your delegate owner directly. You also can refer to `CellFactory` of `RxTableViewReactiveArrayDataSource`. It change the method to block.